# urls like "home.asp" redirect in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I need to rebuild a website (in old they use classic ASP but they want to make it now MVC 4) and they dont want to change the urls. for example if the search screen's url is blabla.com/search.asp they want to keep it like this. But mvc doesn't allow to make urls like "search.asp". I want to keep url like this but render search View. Am I need to do this all one by one or there is a dynamic way for it?

for example

```
requested url = "blabla.com/string variable" 
if variable.Substring(variable.Length - 4) == ".asp";
return View("variable.Substring(0, (variable.Length - 4))")
```

Note: Syntax is all wrong, I know. I just tried to explain the condition..

Note2: They want this because of "SEO" things. they don't want to lose their ratings. any method that doesn't change anything for google, they will accept that method I guess.

Comment: will they accept redirects? You could use IIS rewrite rules to change requests from the old version to the new.

Comment: There's no such thing as "MVC 4.5". ASP.NET MVC is a library and is versioned separately from .NET and ASP.NET.

Comment: They want this because of "SEO" things. they don't want to lose their ratings. If it doesn't change anything for google, they will accept that method I guess. What do you think?

Comment: I changed it to mvc :) You right @mason.

Comment: You still have the question tagged as "asp.net-mvc-4" and you mention in the text MVC 4.5". Like I said, no such thing as MVC 4.5, and I highly doubt they want you to rebuild an app using MVC 4, the last release of which was in 2014.

Comment: You are totally right @mason. They want to make it rebuild via MVC 4. thank you for it. I changed it.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive they want you to build the app using MVC 4? Like I said, the last release of that was 2014. I find it much more likely they want you to build on [MVC 5.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/5.2.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things.

1. Define a route for *.asp
2. Add an handler for *.asp

**RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultAsp",
        url: "{controller}/{action}.asp/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Handler (WebConfig)**

(This one needs to be inserted inside `/system.webServer/handlers`

```
  <add name="AspFileHandler" path="*.asp" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Doing this you are also making all URL's built with MVC available with .asp, that means that if you have an anchor that calls another View, that view will have the normal mvc URL with .asp suffix.

**Note**

This is generic, you only need to add this line once.
Home/Index displayed are just the default Controller and Action.

**Note 2**

Forgot to explain the handler.

You need it because IIS thinks you are asking for an ASP file an it'll try to reach that page and return an error since it doesn't exist.

With this handler you are allowing your application to handle those pages itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works with GET actions since we are only specifying `GET` in the handler. If you also want POST, just change it to `GET,POST`

Answer (score 1):

MVC does allows you to write a Route containing an extension, and pointing it to a specific Controller:

In RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapRoute("Test", "test.asp", new {controller = "Test", action = "test" });
}
```

Then, in your TestController.cs:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var obj = new Foo();
        //Do some processing
        return View(obj);
    }
}
```

In this way, you can access `http://www.foo.com/test.asp` without issues, and maintaining the `.asp` your client requires.

Comment: Thank you Fabio it is very close the solution of Leandro but I.needed to make it more dynamic so I choosed Leandro's answer as verified. But thank you for all :)